# About solving an equation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let us consider an equation of the form

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\sin(y\ln n)}{n^{x}}=-\frac{y}{a}$$

My question is:

Is it possible to say that $y=0$ is the only solution of this equation.

Comment: much better thanks Andrei

Comment: This series does depend on $x$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I speak about the equation.

Comment: The solution does depend on $x$ !

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Ok corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For large $x$ ($x=10$ on the plot), the LHS divided by $y$ is very similar to a $\text{sinc}$ so that for large $a$ there can probably be numerous solutions.

[image]

(For smaller $x$, I guess that the behavior is oscillating anyway and numerous roots remain possible.)

Comment: @E.J: it is especially possible to say that $y=0$ is not the only solution !

Answer (score 2):

The sum can be written in terms of the Riemann zeta function:
$$\begin{align}
 F(x+iy)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\sin(y\ln n)}{n^{x}}&=\Im \left((1-2^{1-(x+iy)})\zeta(x+iy)\right) .\end{align}
$$
This is because $\sin (y\ln n) = -\Im n^{ -iy}$. The series converges if $x>0$ and the formula holds by the analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta function.

Let $\rho=1/2+it_0$ with $t_0\approx14.134725$, the imaginary part of the first  nontrivial zero of zeta function. Then by the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)), $F(\tau)\neq 0$ for some $\tau=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|\tau-\rho|<0.1$.  Then we find $a$ such that $F(\tau)=-\frac ya$. This $y$ is a solution to the desired equation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it's the right answer. You can find a pair $(x,y)$ that satisfies the equation. For example, you can choose $x=2$ and then solve $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\sin(y\ln n)}{n^{2}}=-\frac{y}{a}$$